# Apache Camel - conditional retry maximum times depending on exchange property; if condition not met, 0

Tags: apache-camel

How can I set retry times dynamically depending on some property of the exchange?

I want to send an event to destination and then process the response. If this event is `positive == true`, then I want to retry 3 times synchronously; if not, just don't retry.

```java
from(RETRY_ONLINE_ENDPOINT)
        .routeId(RETRY_ONLINE_ROUTE_ID)
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${exchangeProperty.positive} != true"))
                .onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Caught: " + simple("${exchangeProperty.CamelExceptionCaught}") + ", retried attempts: " + simple("${header.CamelRedeliveryCounter}"))
                .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                .handled(true)
                .bean(PostRetryBean.class)
            .endChoice()
            .otherwise()
                .bean(PostRetryBean.class)
            .endChoice()
        .end();
```

But I got exception `onException()` must be set at top level error.

If I move `onException()` to top level, then compile does not pass. MaximizeRetryTimes cannot follow `when()`.

So, how can I conditionally set maximum retry times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I find it: use `onWhen()` to additionally check a condition to decide whether to use this `onException()` route.

```java
    /**
     * Sets an additional predicate that should be true before the onException is triggered.
     * <p/>
     * To be used for fine grained controlling whether a thrown exception should be intercepted by this exception type
     * or not.
     *
     * @param  predicate predicate that determines true or false
     * @return           the builder
     */
    public OnExceptionDefinition onWhen(@AsPredicate Predicate predicate) {
        setOnWhen(new WhenDefinition(predicate));
        return this;
    }
```

So it becomes:

```java
onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class).onWhen(simple("${exchangeProperty.positive} == true"))
                .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                .handled(true)
                .bean(RecoverableExceptionHandler.class)
                .to(REPLY_QUEUE_ENDPOINT);

onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class).onWhen(simple("${exchangeProperty.positive} == false"))
                .handled(true)
                .bean(RecoverableExceptionHandler.class)
                .to(REPLY_QUEUE_ENDPOINT);
```